# error the reader is open?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

```
Private Sub TbDepot_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TbDepot.KeyUp
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sap;Integrated Security=True")
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd0 As New SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Depot where Code=@code", con)
    cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", TbDepot.Text)
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = cmd0.ExecuteReader()

    If (dr.Read()) Then
        LDepot.Text = dr.Item("Name")
        dr.Close()
        cmd1 = New SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.Item", con)
        'cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depot", TbDepot.Text)
        da1 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)

        dt1 = New DataTable()
        da1.Fill(dt1)
        GvRates.DataSource = dt1
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please type the correct entry")
        TbDepot.Clear()

    End If
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Please check the following code.

Comment: _"error the reader is open?"_ is that everything you want to tell us about your issue? No further description, no stacktrace or line numbers? I feel like someone dumps something at my feets and says i should take it.

Comment: sir m actually a fresher and developing a software in vb.net and i want verify my code that whether it is correct or not

Comment: obviously it is not correct, otherwise you would not get that error. but you should tell us more than what you provided in the title.

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR description of the problem.  A title and some code are NEVER enough. Language may be an issue but you have to try.

Comment: you need to `dr.close()` like you did with `con`. Or more preferably start taking advantage of `Using` statements where these kind of things are handled for you. I would also like to add that the `KeyUp` event is a bad place for this as you are going to check the database with each keystroke. Not to mention that you would drive your users crazy having to close a message box with each keypress until a valid name is found. Maybe move this to some type of leave event of the textbox so that it checks when the user has entered a complete name.